# Webpack Hot Module Replacement with Node Config?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

So ive looked at documentation for webpack HMR, and cant seem to find a way to hot module load a server side file.  For example, i have a config file, written in typescript, that I need to be able to reload on change to that config file.  So i will need to update after compile.  The docs are all favored towards using webpack dev server except this one [HMR](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/hot-module-replacement) which doesnt explain what my webpack config should look like in order to use HMR.  Any help or suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/docs/issues/45 might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

You can set it up in a very similar way to client side HMR:

1) Target 'node':

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    target: 'node'
    ...
}
```

2) Enable hot module replacement, either through the cli option `--hot` or through config:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
    ...
};
```

3) Include HMR management code in your entry point:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    entry: [
        'webpack/hot/poll?1000', // This differs from client side HMR
        'app.js'
    ]
    ...
};
```

4) Teach your code how to hot update using `module.hot.accept`:

> NOTE: This is often abstracted away by a loader.

```
// app.js
let config = require('./config');
setInterval(() => {
    console.log(config.FOO_BAR);
}, 2000);

// NOTE: This would need to be done everywhere you use './config' so you might want to create a loader to generate it.
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./config', () => {
        config = require('./config');
    });
}
```

4) Compile the bundle in watch mode.

Comment: How to do something similar with Typescript? How to replace typescript imports?